# Redis with even number of Sentinels

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

If I have a setup of 3 sentinel nodes with quorum of 2 and one of the Sentinel node fails, during failover process the Quorum can still be reached with 2 sentinels that are up, but what happens if leader election fails?

From what I have read, leader election happens via a voting mechanism, so there is a chance that both the Sentinels will vote for any 1 sentinel and leader election is successful and failover can begin.

But what if each sentinel voted for itself and leader election could not happen? Will the leader election process be triggered again until a leader is selected or the failover process will abort?